# What are some appropriate uses for Java Custom Annotations?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, annotations

Most of the articles I see on Custom Annotations have clear examples on how to create and use them, but they offer mostly trivial problems being solved. Other that an executor pattern such as in JUnit, these examples do not lead me to any realizations about how I could apply Custom Annotations to simplify code.

I understand how to use them, but I'm interested to know any scenarios I should consider creating them. Are there common Object Oriented Patterns where it can simplify the solution to use Custom Annotations?

Comment: If you don't like my question at least explain why. I'm happy to try and improve it.

Answer (score 6):

You use them when you want to either inject or extract something to/from an object via reflection.

Unless you're writing some sort of framework, client, or re-usable code, typically this isn't something you're going to do.

A concrete example would be my [annotations in the Riak Java client](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/tree/develop/src/main/java/com/basho/riak/client/annotations).

For ORM (Object Relational Mapping) I created a complete set of annotations that allows the user to annotate their own classes so that they can simply say "Please store this in Riak" and pass in their own object. The annotations allow the bucket, key, content-type, vector clock, etc, to be annotated, and using reflection I extract that information and build the appropriate wire protocol object to then send to Riak.

They also allow for deserialization to a user object when getting a response back from Riak; all the response data is injected to the user's annotated fields/methods.

Pretty much any library that has some sort of ORM or injection mechanism provides annotations for you to use. And that's why they're written. As you mention, JUnit is one, but things like JSON parsers are another good example (Gson, Jackson). Spring is a huge example.